# com.squareup.okhttp.HttpResponseCache Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpResponseCache'

Tags: android, gradle, httpresponsecache

I'm trying to compile an Android project in Android Studio which imports:

com.squareup.okhttp.HttpResponseCache

I'm getting an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpResponseCache' "

I've tried adding in the gradle the following dependencies without success:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
```

Which library/s should I include to use HttpResponseCache?

Comment: `android.net.http` ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/package-summary.html

Comment: That's a different one, I want to use HttResponseCache from the com.squareup.okhttp library

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html), you should import `android.net.http`.

Comment: I want to compile an existing project available in Github

Comment: What is the project? Maybe I can try on my computer to see the errors.

Comment: Wikipedia Android app

Comment: Wikipedia Android app (an ancient version): https://github.com/wikimedia/apps-android-wikipedia/releases/tag/releases%2F2.0-beta-2014-07-16
The class using such library is: OkHttpConnectionFactory

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `com.squareup.okhttp.HttpResponseCache` was [deprecated](http://square.github.io/okhttp/1.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpResponseCache.html) after v1. I do not see it included in the package after v2.0.0

If you want to use it, add:

```
'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0'
```